# What would it be like to drive around on 4 flat tires?

Tags: tires

This question probably doesn't fit that well into this forum, but at the same time I think the people of this forum would have the best knowledge to answer it. This seems like a technical qualifier to me, but if you disagree, feel free to uproot the question and place it somewhere else.

What kind of control would a person have if they were driving around on 4 flat tires? I'm especially interested in what it would be like if they were driving very vigorously or chaotically. Could you take turns on 4 flats if you were driving fast? How long would it take before the rims cut through the rubber and started sparking against the pavement?

Comment: Driving control : dangerous , do NOT attempt it to find out...

Comment: If it was a good idea, the Police wouldn't use Stinger devices to slow/stop cars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First point would be why??? Next point acceleration would be terrible. After the first few rotations the tire beads would separate from the rim seat. The result would be the wheels spinning and the tires not moving much. Braking effect would be the same, the wheels would stop but the tires could still roll around the rim. Steering would be sluggish as the tires would roll off the rim leaving the metal wheel in contact with the ground. The contact area of the wheel is so small that the cars inertia would push it in the direction of travel regardless of the wheel direction.